# Trouble stopping a div from dropping down while resizing window

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, responsive-design

I've tried fixing this myself for awhile now, it seems like an easy problem but I'm lost.

I have two divs one with float left, one with float right. The right one has a margin-left of 40px and the width needs to adjust as the window gets smaller. At the moment once the two divs touch it is dropping down.

Please check this to further understand :) https://jsfiddle.net/to7g54sn/1/

```
#contentwrapper {
width: 100%;
max-width: 1160px;
float: right;
margin-top: 154px;
margin-left: 40px;
}

#navigation {
width: 150px;
margin-left: -120px;
float: left;
}
```

(The preview needs a width of 1330px to see the divs before they drop).

The margin-left: 40px on the right div needs to constantly be applied, if you scroll down on the resized window you will see the left div overlaps. I think the javascript is making this issue tough but I'm not entirely sure.

Comment: I think what you’re looking for is a 2-col layout where one column is fixed-width and the other is fluid, right? If so, check out this simple demo using negative margins http://codepen.io/tedw/pen/azqMRL?editors=1100 You could also use `display: table-cell;` or `display: flex;` to do this.

Comment: Use reltive div widths http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21136975/fixed-menu-on-left-and-content-scrollable

Comment: @TedWhitehead ...Thanks for the help. I tried incorporating what you wrote in my jsfiddle but I was unable to achieve what I wanted. This may because of my javascript maybe? Or possibly because I'm struggling to understand what you mean. Any chance you could have a quick look at my jsfiddle? Or reference me to some information further explaining your solution. :)

Comment: @Keloo Thanks for the link but my question is a little more complicated with his, the answers didn't help too much. The javascript is making this a little difficult.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have a easy solution. Just use this css below:

```
#contentwrapper {
    width: calc(100% - 70px);
}
```

Check this on [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/sarowerj/to7g54sn/5/)

Comment: Thanks a lot man. Could you explain how this works just so I can learn?

Comment: It's like dynamic css. It will get it's parent's full width's 70px less.