# Make position: fixed with out change resolution

Tags: javascript, html, css

I don't know how to explain it you could understand it well. I have a left navigation and container on rest of website in one line. Navigation has 88px width when `.right-column-wrapper` 100% of rest available space. In the `.right-column-wrapper` I have a left and right column in line, each one has 50%. When I add `position: fixed` to the `.right-column`, `.right-column` takes 50% of browser width but not the 50% of `.right-column-wrapper`

**HTML Code:**

```
<div class="page-wrapper">
        <!-- Left side navigation -->
        <div class="nav-bar-left">
            <a href="" class="w-nav-brand">
                <img src="https://i.imgur.com/0f8pGKD.png" alt="">
            </a>
            <nav role="navigation" class="nav-menu-left">
                <a href="who.html" class="nav-link active">who</a>
                <a href="what.html" class="nav-link">what</a>
                <a href="why.html" class="nav-link">why</a>
                <a href="contact.html" class="nav-link">contact</a>
            </nav>
            <div class="nav-left-social-icons">
                <a href="https://twitter.com" target="_blank" class="social-icon-link">
                    <img src="https://assets.website-files.com/5b17159f88941cfc367e81a3/5b1715a088941c0f047e81f3_twitter-icon.svg" alt="">
                </a>
                <a href="https://twitter.com" target="_blank" class="social-icon-link">
                    <img src="https://assets.website-files.com/5b17159f88941cfc367e81a3/5b1715a088941c314a7e81d9_instagram-icon.svg" alt="">
                </a>
                <a href="https://twitter.com" target="_blank" class="social-icon-link">
                    <img src="https://assets.website-files.com/5b17159f88941cfc367e81a3/5b1715a088941c861b7e82d0_facebook-icon.svg" alt="">
                </a>
            </div>
        </div>
        <!-- Right components -->
        <div class="right-column-wrapper">
            <div class="column left-column">
                <div class="left-column-top">
                    <div class="split-content">
                        <h1 class="split-content-headline">the story so far</h1>
                        <p class="content-v2">
                            Scotty Huss is an ultimate leader in helping you believing yourself to success. While Breaking records at a young age, yet teaching others to dulpicate his success, Scotty is an aspiring entrepreneur, investor, & mentor.
                            <br> <br>
                            Mr. Huss is most known for being one of the youngest top earners in the network marketing industry. 
                            He has already accomplished more then most people accomplish in a lifetime. He helps people expand their 
                            lives financially by providing different services that encourage individuals to multiply their money, add 
                            belief to their lives, and practice personal development characteristics + growth techniques that help people 
                            learn the law of attaction.
                            <br> <br>
                            Scotty serves as a great example to his team on what can take place when someone truly commits.
                            Scotty travels the world to help others become financially free. He currently resides in Florida 
                            but is always on the move with his organization. His mission is to impact the lives of a billion 
                            people around the world in a positive way & teach those who are willling to achieve greatness 
                            learning specific skillsets.
                        </p>
                        <div class="launching-beyond-wrapper">
                            <div class="video-thumbnail-wrap">
                                
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="left-column-footer">

                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="column right-column who-site-right-column"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
 </div>
```

**CS code**

```
.page-wrapper {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    display: flex;
}
.page-wrapper .nav-bar-left {
    width: 88px;
    height: 100%;
    background: #fff;
    border-right: 1px solid #cfcfcf;
    float: left;
    position: relative;
}
.page-wrapper .nav-bar-left .w-nav-brand {
    display: flex;
    width: 88px;
    height: 88px;
    -webkit-box-pack: center;
    -webkit-justify-content: center;
    -ms-flex-pack: center;
    justify-content: center;
    -webkit-box-align: center;
    -webkit-align-items: center;
    -ms-flex-align: center;
    align-items: center;
}
.page-wrapper .nav-bar-left .nav-menu-left {
    font-family: "Oswald";
    position: absolute;
    left: -196px;
    top: 328px;
    width: 480px;
    -webkit-transform: rotate(-90deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(-90deg);
    transform: rotate(-90deg);
    text-align: right;
}
.page-wrapper .nav-bar-left .nav-menu-left .nav-link {
    position: static;
    display: inline;
    padding: 12px 14px;
    opacity: 0.5;
    -webkit-transition: opacity 400ms ease;
    transition: opacity 400ms ease;
    font-family: Oswald, sans-serif;
    color: #111;
    font-size: 12px;
    line-height: 32px;
    font-weight: 400;
    text-decoration: none;
    opacity: .5;
    letter-spacing: 2px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}
.page-wrapper .nav-bar-left .nav-menu-left .nav-link.active {
    opacity: 1;
}
.page-wrapper .nav-bar-left .nav-left-social-icons {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0px;
    right: 0px;
    bottom: 0px;
    display: -webkit-box;
    display: -webkit-flex;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: flex;
    padding-top: 8px;
    padding-bottom: 20px;
    -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
    -webkit-box-direction: normal;
    -webkit-flex-direction: column;
    -ms-flex-direction: column;
    flex-direction: column;
    -webkit-box-pack: center;
    -webkit-justify-content: center;
    -ms-flex-pack: center;
    justify-content: center;
    -webkit-box-align: center;
    -webkit-align-items: center;
    -ms-flex-align: center;
    align-items: center;
}
.page-wrapper .nav-bar-left .nav-left-social-icons .social-icon-link {
    display: -webkit-box;
    display: -webkit-flex;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: flex;
    padding: 8px;
    -webkit-box-pack: center;
    -webkit-justify-content: center;
    -ms-flex-pack: center;
    justify-content: center;
    -webkit-box-align: center;
    -webkit-align-items: center;
    -ms-flex-align: center;
    align-items: center;
    opacity: 0.4;
    -webkit-transition: opacity 400ms ease;
    transition: opacity 400ms ease;
}
.page-wrapper .nav-bar-left .nav-left-social-icons .social-icon-link img {
    max-width: 100%;
    vertical-align: middle;
    display: inline-block;
}
.page-wrapper .right-column-wrapper {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    display: flex;
}
.page-wrapper .right-column-wrapper .column {
    width: 50%;
    height: 100%;
}
.page-wrapper .right-column-wrapper .column.left-column::-webkit-scrollbar {
    width: 0px;  /* Remove scrollbar space */
    background: transparent;  /* Optional: just make scrollbar invisible */
}   
.page-wrapper .right-column-wrapper .column.right-column {
    background: url(https://i.imgur.com/4Mmj0E8.jpg);
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: center;
}
.page-wrapper .right-column-wrapper .column .left-column-top {
    width: 100%;
    background: #fff;
    height: fit-content;
    padding-bottom: 100px;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #cfcfcf;
}
.page-wrapper .right-column-wrapper .column .left-column-footer {
    width: 100%;
    height: 400px;
    background: red;
}
.page-wrapper .right-column-wrapper .column .split-content {
    padding: 104px 6% 120px;
    height: 100%;
    margin: auto;
}
.page-wrapper .right-column-wrapper .column .split-content .split-content-headline {
    margin-top: 0px;
    margin-bottom: 24px;
    font-family: Oswald, sans-serif;
    font-size: 44px;
    line-height: 52px;
    font-weight: 500;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}
.page-wrapper .right-column-wrapper .column .split-content .content-v2 {
    font-family: "Karla";
    color: #777;
    margin-bottom: 24px;
    font-size: 15px;
    line-height: 24px;
}
.page-wrapper .right-column-wrapper .column .split-content .content-v2::first-letter {
    font-family: Oswald, sans-serif;
    color: #faaf52;
    font-size: 46px;
    float: left;
    margin: 0.7rem 0rem;
    padding-right: 7px;
}
.page-wrapper .right-column-wrapper .column .split-content .launching-beyond-wrapper {
    background: #fff;
    border-top: 1px solid #cfcfcf;
    border-bottoM: 1px solid #cfcfcf;
    width: 100%;
    height: 160px;
    position: relative;
}
.page-wrapper .right-column-wrapper .column .split-content .launching-beyond-wrapper .video-thumbnail-wrap {
    width: 136px;
    height: 92px;
    background: url(https://i.imgur.com/1LPdxEM.jpg);
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: center;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    bottoM: 0;
    margin: auto;
}
.page-wrapper .right-column-wrapper .column .split-content .launching-beyond-wrapper .video-thumbnail-wrap:before {
    content: '';
    width: 31px;
    height: 31px;
    bottom: 0;
    right: 0;
    background-color: #faaf52;
    background-image: url('https://assets.website-files.com/5b17159f88941cfc367e81a3/5b1715a088941c88717e824f_play-icon.svg');
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    position: absolute;
}
```

Comment: I want to the right column with the background stay when scrolling

Comment: I do not know how to add one

Comment: try this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21136975/fixed-menu-on-left-and-content-scrollable

Comment: Your post is not clear. I suggest you rewrite it. If english is a little hard for you, try to use some translator to help you.

Answer (score 0):

You can set height and width of background image from right column and use `calc` to calculate width of left column

```
.page-wrapper .right-column-wrapper .column.right-column {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    width: 300px;
    height: 500px;
    ...
}

.page-wrapper .right-column-wrapper .left-column {
    width: calc(100% - 300px);
}
```

Here is the [sample](https://codepen.io/KaungKZ/pen/WNxLXOr?editors=1100)